# filtering not working after pointing filterStyleClass to a function primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi guys im trying to add a delete icon in my filter. So i use filterStyle class to point to a function. and it works fine i see the icon when i click it the field clears. However the filter doesnt filter anything when im trying to search.`<style>
            span.deleteicon {
                position: relative;
            }
            span.deleteicon span {
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                top: 5px;
                right: 0px;
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;
                background: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflo/img/sprites.png?v=4') 0 -690px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            span.deleteicon input {
                padding-right: 16px;
            }
        </style>`

my function is like `$('input.deletable').wrap('<span class="deleteicon" />').after($('<span/>').click(function() {
                    $(this).prev('input').val('').focus();
                }));`

and called in my filter `filterStyleClass="deletable"` i understand my filter uses an ajax call is this affected anyway by this.

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't look like JSF at all.

You can check out the primefaces filter example.

```
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml
```

Comment: it is not jsf. the first part is a style to place my icon , the second part is my jquery function.  filterStyle class is used by primefaces to style the filter in which i call the function deletable. my problem is that the filtering doesnt filter after adding  this callfilterstyleClass